# Rufus bootable drive not being recognized

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I created a bootable drive with ubuntu version 20.04.3 LTS using Rufus to a 32 gigabite flash drive. When I restart the computer and open the boot menu, it doesn't show the drive or the option to boot ubuntu. Does anybody know why or how I could fix this? Currently I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: At boot try pressing F8, F9 or F12 to boot the USB.

Comment: Do you know if your BIOS is UEFI or EFI? Also, is secure boot or fast boot disabled? Also, what computer are you using? Like, model, brand and architecture (ex. X86_64 or ARM) To ask a good question, I would recommend adding the things I asked for in your answer so that users can better answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

(considering that rufus not failed) **In BIOS you need to**:

1. disable `"Secure Boot"` or `"Fast Boot"`(depends on your system, what is present)
2. enable `"Booting from USB"`
3. In case you had previously selected `"Legacy Mode"` then check if you have `"UEFI with CSM"`, `"UEFI hybrid"` or just `"CSM"` and select it instead. If you had just `"UEFI"` than it's ok.

   [number 3.] depends on how is your current installation done.

**---end of BIOS part---**

Need to mention if you disable `"Secure Boot"` you might encounter Blue Screen and something like BitLocker need to recover you key.
This means your Windows disk is ecrypted. Enable `"Secure Boot"` to be able to boot to Windows and there [disable BitLocker](https://www.minitool.com/news/disable-bitlocker.html).
This [page](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-disabling-secure-boot-and-bitlocker-in-windows/62391) might be helpful.

For first time installing recommend [this part of help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_for_Single_Boot_with_a_Random_Boot_Mode).

Also you might consider reading [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi).